# CSS responsive - after clear both, div pill up/stack instead back to normal

Tags: html, css

i try to learn responsive website. but i get stuck in here

```css
div {
 display: block;
 height: 50px;
}
.header {
 width: 50%;
 background-color: red;
}
.left {
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}
.right {
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 width : 50%;
}
.clear {
 display: none;
 clear: both;
}
.footer {
 width: 50%;
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%">
<div class="header">without float</div>
<div class="header">without float</div>
<div class="left">kiri</div>
<div class="right">kanan</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="footer">after clear xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx</div>
<div class="footer">after clear shshjsjaa shsusus</div>
</body>
</html>
```

why div class footer not back to normal like class header?

as i know clear: both clear :left is erase float: left rule. but i dont know why my footer looks pill up

looks for this image to see the display
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add "Display:none;" with "clear:both". that makes div hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate div with class clear there.

Check this snippet:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}
.header {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body style="width: 100%">

  <div class="header">without float</div>
  <div class="header">without float</div>
  <div class="left">kiri</div>
  <div class="right">kanan</div>
 
  <div class="footer">after clear xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx</div>
  <div class="footer">after clear shshjsjaa shsusus</div>

</body>

</html>
```